# Hook for when a new content type is created?

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

Does a hook exist for when a new content type is created?  If so what is it?  I've looked through the API and nothing has jumped out at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_node_type_insert()` is invoked from `node_type_save()` after the node type is added to the database.

See:
[hook_node_type_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_type_insert/7)